# SearchView как убрать выпадающий список

Tags: java, android, android-search-view

В toolbar встроил SearchView (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView), но мне не нужен выпадающий список, как от него избавиться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(null);`